# How to decrement iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am using c++ stl list of custom defined structs and I have an iterator that goes through that list but at one point I need to decrement and go back a few entries in the list. I tried itt-- but that just gave me a segmentation fault. Is there any other way of doing it.

I also tried this `std::advance(cur_instruc, a);`

Here is what the iterator looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int instruction_ptr;
    int token;
    std::string instruction;
    std::string value;
} decoraded_nodes;

int main () {
    std::list<decoraded_nodes> instruction_list;
    std::list<decoraded_nodes>::iterator it;
    it = instruction_list.begin();

    decoraded_nodes a;
    a.instruction_ptr = 1;
    a.token = 1;
    a.instruction = "1";
    a.value = "2";

    decoraded_nodes b;
    b.instruction_ptr = 1;
    b.token = 1;
    b.instruction = "1";
    b.value = "1";

    decoraded_nodes c;
    c.instruction_ptr = 1;
    c.token = 1;
    c.instruction = "1";
    c.value = "3";

    instruction_list.insert(it, a);
    instruction_list.insert(it, b);
    instruction_list.insert(it, c);

    bool aa = false;
    int bb = 0;

    for (std::list<decoraded_nodes>::iterator cur_instruc = instruction_list.begin(), 
        end = instruction_list.end(); 
        cur_instruc != end; ++cur_instruc) {
        cout << cur_instruc->value;

        bb++;

        if (bb == 1) {
            aa = true;
        }

        if (aa) {
            cur_instruc--;
            aa = false;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As long as you don't decrement it beyond the beginning, and you don't invalidate the iterator (by erasing the element it refers to), that should be fine. Could you post [enough code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: the code above actually works right now...

Comment: So why did you post it? Please post a test case which demonstrates the problem. Without that, it's impossible to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: I don't know why it worked here. I'm building a compiler and here is a like to source https://github.com/gsinghware/pascal_compiler. The problem is in the stack machine in this statement else if (cur_instruc->instruction == "op_jfalse")

Comment: Then perhaps you could reduce whatever that's doing to a simple test case. No-one is likely to trawl through all that code to figure out what might be wrong with it.

Comment: I did reduce it and it works on, see code in description. idk why it's not working in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to change loop "for" variable (in this case - an iterator) inside the loop. Try to crete new iterator inside the loop, when you need to go back and work with this newly created iterator.